# Getting variable from parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can only imagine that this has been asked several times, but I can't find it. Probably cus I'm searching with wrong words

Normally we can do this: `id = $("#someId");` where the id is typically from a html control, looking like this: `<input type="text" id="someId" />`

But now the id will be passed with the function. So I want to do something like this:

```
function someFunct(id) {
    id = $("#"+id +");
```

How can I do this using js/JQuery?

Comment: Don't use the ending `")` part, and you're good to go: `$("#"+id);`

Comment: Just fix your syntax error and it's correct.

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
function someFunct(id) {
    id = $("#"+id +");
```

should be

```
function someFunct(id) {
    id = $("#"+ id);
```